# Monitor Blinks after boot up on Parrot Security OS and not getting started

Tags: boot, parrotsec

My monitor is just blinking and not getting started. I've waited for a long time but no result. Reboot doesn't work also. any solutions?

Comment: When was the last time your monitor working?

Comment: just the morning before that problem...I've faced the same problem with Kali 2017.01 and I switched to parrot...

Comment: Try some non-debian distro eg. `Fedora`